# Jquery Mobile Object has no method 'selectmenu'

Tags: jquery, ajax, mobile

I'm having some trouble refreshing a multi select list after an ajax call with JQuery Mobile. The AJAX call goes fine and I'm executing the following javascript code on success:

```
function(data){
    var myselect = $("select#ureporting_team");
    myselect.selectmenu("refresh", true);
}
```

Which should update the following element:
    `<select multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false" name="ureporting[team]" id="ureporting_team"></select>`

However, in console(chrome), I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'selectmenu'

I'm at a loss as to why this isn't working. I've gone over the documentation several times and I can't seem to find anyone else having this problem. I'm sure it's something small I'm overlooking. Thanks!

edit, Here are the script include tags:
    `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>`
    `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>`
JQMobile seems to be working fine other than this.

Comment: You most likely have a problem with the script tags for including the jQuery and/or selectmenu javascript files. Please post the script tags you are using to reference those libraries.